# sos.dll usage in visual studio 2013

Tags: debugging, windbg, sos

When I am reading docs [about sos.dll @MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx), encounter a note says

> If you are using Visual Studio 2013, SOS.dll is supported in the Windows Debugger within Visual Studio

I know how to use sos.dll in the immediate window in Visual Studio 2012. But how to use sos.dll with visual studio 2013 debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN documentation of [What’s New for the Debugger in Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01xdt7cs.aspx) (Excerpt from the part `Debug With Debugging Tools for Windows`)

> The SOS.dll (SOS Debugging Extension) that helps you debug managed
>   programs in WinDbg, **is not available from the Visual Studio IDE**. See
>   Debugging Managed Code Using the Windows Debugger

Looks like you may need to load them separately as being said [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540665.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get sos.dll to load in Visual Studio 2013 no matter what I tried.

I've resorted to good old WinDbg instead.  I know it's not an ideal answer, but it appears to be the only possible solution to debugging with sos.dll.  I'd really like to use sos.dll in Visual Studio 2013, but WinDbg isn't so bad once you learn its basics.  It's actually very powerful, even if you know very little about the unmanaged world (like me).

[How to load SOS in WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540665.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use SOS from VS 2017. But you will need to install windows driver kit (WDK). Here is a screenshot of me debugging a process with command line debugger within VS 2017.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-user-mode-debugging-in-visual-studio

[image]

Comment: "This feature is not available in Windows 10, version 1507 and later versions of the WDK".  Copied from your link .. sadly, i verified it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Not sure why they removed it. Well then you need to go traditional way then with WinDBg. But I will test at home today and see.