# How can I load SOS in Visual Studio 2017 in Immediate Window in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windbg, sos

I tried this:

```
    1. Create new Windows WinForm Desktop Application in VS2017. (or console)
    2. Build it and Run as Admin.
    3. Enable Native Debugging, Enable Managed compatibility mode
    4. Pause App by Break All, or break in an breakpoint
    5. Open Immediate Windows and type command:

.load SOS
```

error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'

or 
.loadby or !load or load or .Load etc.

Based on article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2007/11/15/sos-your-visual-studio/

Comment: VS2010 was the last VS version that could still do this.  You need to use windbg.

Comment: Why SOS was removed for VS. That is strange. They probably replaced it or guarded by some setting. SOS is part of NET shipping

Comment: SOS is still part of .NET. Use it with WinDbg. It will give the same output as in VS. It's not too difficult.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sos.dll usage in visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749213/sos-dll-usage-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: You may try the free VisualSOS https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AngelHernandezMatos.VisualSO-Extension-1-0

Answer (score 0):

> The procedures shown in this topic require that you have the Windows Driver Kit integrated into Visual Studio. To get the integrated environment, first install Microsoft Visual Studio, and then install the Windows Driver Kit (WDK). For more information, see Windows Driver Development.
>   In Visual Studio, you can enter debugger commands in the Debugger Immediate Window. To open the Debugger Immediate Window, from the Debug menu, choose Windows>Immediate.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/entering-debugger-commands-in-visual-studio

Comment: What are you telling us with this citation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/entering-debugger-commands-in-visual-studio? Have you also noticed "This feature is not available in Windows 10, version 1507 and later versions of the WDK."?

Comment: I have Windows 8 still. So it should work for me. Install WDK and Immediate Windows magically begin understand Debugger commands. I will try